# Attribute field based off intersecting polygon

Tags: arcpy, cursor, bookmarks

I need to add a polygon for each bookmark (which works fine) and then attribute a field based off which Zip Codes the bookmark polygon intersects.

I don't know if I am on the right track. The code completes so there is no error to show you but the field for each polygon is empty.

```
cur = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(outFC, ["SHAPE@", "ZipCode"])
array = arcpy.Array()
for bkmk in arcpy.mapping.ListBookmarks(mxd):
    array.add(arcpy.Point(bkmk.extent.XMin, bkmk.extent.YMin))
    array.add(arcpy.Point(bkmk.extent.XMin, bkmk.extent.YMax))
    array.add(arcpy.Point(bkmk.extent.XMax, bkmk.extent.YMax))
    array.add(arcpy.Point(bkmk.extent.XMax, bkmk.extent.YMin))
    array.add(arcpy.Point(bkmk.extent.XMin, bkmk.extent.YMin))
    polygon = arcpy.Polygon(array)

    # Calculate Zip Code
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(zipCodesSHP, "zipCodesLYR")
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("zipCodesLYR", "INTERSECT", polygon, "", "NEW_SELECTION")
    zipCodes = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor ("zipCodesLYR", "Zip_Code")]
    zipCode = ", ".join("\"" + str(zipCodes) + "\"")

    # Insert polygon and information  
    cur.insertRow([polygon, zipCode])
    array.removeAll()
```

Comment: Looks like you've got 'zipCodes' and 'zipCode' mixed up...do you mean to insert 'zipCode'?

Comment: Yes Wayne you are correct however it is still the same problem. When I retyped it in here I typed it wrong.

Comment: Do u need python solution or mixed? if mixed then create feature from bookmarks and then run spatial join. Python solution takes time..Does Xmin and YMin properties of bookmark is completely inside the zipCodesSHP layer otherwise u will mess up the thing.

Comment: Check the zipCode variable with a print or AddMessage statement to make sure you're getting what you expect to use with your cursor...also check the size of the field.

Comment: When I run the spatial join it adds multiple rows in the output if it is a one to many join. How do I merge these into one and add the ", " between each Zip Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is your mistake:

zipCode = ", ".join("\"" + str(zipCodes) + "\"")

In short, 'join' is expecting an iterable sequence and you're destroying that with str(zipCodes).  Instead the line should be something like:

zipCode = ', '.join([str(i) for i in zipCodes])

[Note:  str(zipCodes) is actually iterable, but in your case is nonsense because the join is iterating by 'slicing' the resultant string rather than the intended sequence (list) of zip codes.]

Comment: That fixed an issue with my code. It is still not attributing anything. The ZipCodes Shapefile is for the whole country and the polygon is definitely inside that. I have checked that the  output is completely inside the ZipCodes Shapefile.

Comment: What have you done to fix the problem?  Is your destination field, ZipCode, the proper type and of adequate length?  Have you inserted a print statement to 'see' what the zipCode var holds before the insert?

Comment: I am afraid your answer solves the OP's problem. How will you track the zipcode against the shape of each feature with this  joining approach.I mean zipcode of Texas will be added to New York!!!

Comment: No, shouldn't be a problem...notice the sel by loc line using the bookmark extent geometry.  The OP wants to list all intersecting zip code features and add it to the output.  The search cursor honors the sel by loc, so that's correct.  It's up to the OP to have bookmarks with reasonably limited extent to prevent a case as you mention.

Answer (score 0):

I roughly tested your problem and the below code worked for me. Just change the path. Final output is name ***bookmark_joined*** delete unnecessary fields from it. I generated bounding box of bookmarks then centroid of them, to ensure the totally insideness of location of bookmarks in zip shapes. Please clean the pc, i mean, delete intermediate data after script runs.

```
    import arcpy, os
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
    # The map with the bookmarks
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Users\USER_NAME\Desktop\gissta\rkws.mxd")

    outFC = r'C:\Users\USER_NAME\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\bookmark'
    bookmark_centroid = r'C:\Users\USER_NAME\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\bookmark_centroid'
    bookmark_joined =  r'C:\Users\USER_NAME\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\bookmark_joined'

    template = r'C:\Users\USER_NAME\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\template'

    if arcpy.Exists(outFC):
        arcpy.Delete_management(outFC)
    arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(os.path.dirname(outFC),
                                        os.path.basename(outFC), 
                                        "POLYGON", template, 
                                        spatial_reference=template)

    cur = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(outFC, ["SHAPE@", "Name"])
    array = arcpy.Array()
    for bkmk in arcpy.mapping.ListBookmarks(mxd):
        array.add(arcpy.Point(bkmk.extent.XMin, bkmk.extent.YMin))
        array.add(arcpy.Point(bkmk.extent.XMin, bkmk.extent.YMax))
        array.add(arcpy.Point(bkmk.extent.XMax, bkmk.extent.YMax))
        array.add(arcpy.Point(bkmk.extent.XMax, bkmk.extent.YMin))
        # To close the polygon, add the first point again
        array.add(arcpy.Point(bkmk.extent.XMin, bkmk.extent.YMin))
        cur.insertRow([arcpy.Polygon(array), bkmk.name])
        array.removeAll()
    del cur
    arcpy.FeatureToPoint_management(outFC,bookmark_centroid,"CENTROID")
    arcpy.Intersect_analysis ([bookmark_centroid, template], bookmark_joined)
```

Comment: Incidentally, you should be able to shorten the lines generating points, such as "array.add(arcpy.Point(bkmk.extent.XMin, bkmk.extent.YMin))" to "array.add(bkmk.extent.lowerLeft)", etc., as these statements directly return a point obj for the array.